# Running find & grep, and include path in the output

Tags: fedora, grep, find

On at least CentOS systems and previous versions of Fedora, I could run the following command and get a list of files with the corresponding grep matches:

`$ find -name "version.php" -type f | xargs grep "^\$wp_version"
site.com/wp-includes/version.php:$wp_version = '4.7.3';`

Apparently though on at least Fedora 22 and newer, running that same command no longer includes the path and filenames:

`find -name "version.php" -type f | xargs grep "^\$wp_version"
$wp_version = '4.7.3';`

I know I can include -l to show just the path, but is there a way to include the path without dropping the match? I don't see anything in the man file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CentOS/Fedora, so assuming GNU grep, [which has the following switch](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Output-Line-Prefix-Control.html#Output-Line-Prefix-Control):

```
-H, --with-filename
   Print the file name for each match.  This is the default 
   when there is more than one file to search.
```

In other words, the difference in behaviour might be just that in the first case, find catches more than one file, making `grep` list the file names. If it matches only one file in the second case, the names would be missing.

So, add `-H` manually to force it.

Comment: thanks, any idea why that is not in the man grep? By the way, it works without the -H on CentOS, it's Fedora where it wasn't working.

Comment: Or you could just slip in `/dev/null` to `grep` to make the filename+match to always be printed: `find ... | xargs grep version /dev/null`